# XPath preceding depth-first tree element

Tags: xpath, xslt

I have a tree structure:

```
<pages>
    <page id="1">
        <page id="1A" />
        <page id="1B" />
    </page>
    <page id="2" />
    <page id="3">
        <page id="3A" />
        <page id="3B" />
        <page id="3C" />
    </page>
</pages>
```

I want to emit "previous" links with XSLT. I have succeeded in creating "next" links.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/pages">
        <pages>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//page">
                <page id="{@id}" prev="???" next="{(child::page|following::page)/@id}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </pages>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
$ xsltproc test.xsl test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pages>
  <page id="1" prev="" next="1A"/>
  <page id="1A" prev="1" next="1B"/>
  <page id="1B" prev="1A" next="2"/>
  <page id="2" prev="1B" next="3"/>
  <page id="3" prev="2" next="3A"/>
  <page id="3A" prev="3" next="3B"/>
  <page id="3B" prev="3A" next="3C"/>
  <page id="3C" prev="3B" next=""/>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
            <page id="{@id}" prev="{(ancestor::page[1]/@id|preceding::page[1]/@id)[last()]}" next="{(child::page|following::page)/@id}" />
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: Interestingly, Saxon internally has an ancestor-or-preceding axis for use with xsl:number.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0 (with a node-set() extension function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/pages">
    <xsl:variable name="all-pages">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//page"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <pages>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($all-pages)/page">
            <page id="{@id}" prev="{preceding-sibling::page[1]/@id}" next="{following-sibling::page[1]/@id}" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </pages>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```